# Sorta, Kinda got the new nav

Tags: support, new-nav

So I wanted to be part of beta testing the new navigation, so I checked the box in my preferences.

After waiting for some time the new navigation for the question section showed up, but the header has not changed (I changed to the new navigation yesterday). I assume it is supposed to be white with the buttons in different positions, but it shows the old header. Is this because I have 500+ rep?

[image]

Comment: "new-nav" !== "top-bar".

Comment: @Kendra. Thanks! You should post that as an answer.

Comment: If you're still hoping to help beta test this, they've opened an opt-in option now. I updated my answer with information.

Comment: @Kendra Danke. Really exited that you shared this information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The checkbox you marked is for the "New Navigation Beta", which is *only* for the question section changes. That's been in beta for a while now, so the option has likewise been there for a while now.

What you're wanting to test is the new top bar, which doesn't have an opt in. It's an A/B test, so no one is given the option to test it. It's only shown, randomly, for users who meet the requirements. In this case, the requirements are having 499 or less reputation.

Your guess that you can't see it because you have 500 or more rep is correct, though not at all affected by the option you checked in your profile.

---

Update:

There is now an option in the profile's "Preferences" section to enable the new top bar.

To opt in to the new top bar:

Go to your Stack Overflow (not Meta) profile and click "Edit Profile and Settings". Select "Preferences" from the left hand navigation menu. Scroll to the bottom, and check the box for "New Site Navigation" to opt in. Note that this may take some time to be visible, but the option *is* now there. The previous "New Nav" feature is listed just above it as "New Question Filter" and will still only enable the question tabs.